# How to return a command when pressing on a button with Telegram Bot

Tags: python, button, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to return a command with python-telegram-bot when I press a button with `InlineKeyboardButton`. I am trying the following but with no luck:

```
 bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, 
        text='/help', 
        parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
```

Answer (score 8):

First define your button by callback data:

```
import telegram
HELP_BUTTON_CALLBACK_DATA = 'A unique text for help button callback data'
help_button = telegram.InlineKeyboardButton(
    text='Help me', # text that show to user
    callback_data=HELP_BUTTON_CALLBACK_DATA # text that send to bot when user tap button
    )
```

Show help button to user in `start` command or another way:

```
def command_handler_start(bot, update):
    chat_id = update.message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        text='Hello ...',
        reply_markup=telegram.InlineKeyboardMarkup([help_button]),
        )
```

Define help command handler:

```
def command_handler_help(bot, update):
    chat_id = update.message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        text='Help text for user ...',
        )
```

Handle callback data:

```
def callback_query_handler(bot, update):
    cqd = update.callback_query.data
    #message_id = update.callback_query.message.message_id
    #update_id = update.update_id
    if cqd == HELP_BUTTON_CALLBACK_DATA:
        command_handler_help(bot, update)
    # elif cqd == ... ### for other buttons
```

At last add handlers to your bot and start polling

```
update = telegram.ext.Updater('BOT_TOKEN')
bot = update.bot
dp = update.dispatcher
print('Your bot is --->', bot.username)
dp.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler('start', command_handler_start))
dp.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler('help', command_handler_help))
dp.add_handler(telegram.ext.CallbackQueryHandler(callback_query_handler))
update.start_polling()
```

Comment: the code works perfectly fine when I try to send a normal text when I press the button, but I cannot seem to make the following work: `/mon name`. It doesn't seem to recognize commands which are send by the bot itself. Do you know how to address this issue?

Comment: reply_markup needs to be a list of lists. So it should be `telegram.InlineKeyboardMarkup([[help_button]])`.